# Why is there a `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` entry in my `git branch -l -a` output?

Tags: git, branch

I don't understand the second line in the output to `git branch -l -a`: `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master`.

```
git branch -l -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Is that a leftover from another operation? Should I clean it up? And how would I do that?

Usually I work with git on the cli, but on this local repository I experimented with `TortoiseGit` to find an easy git workflow for a friend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "origin/HEAD" shown when running "git branch -r"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354312/why-is-origin-head-shown-when-running-git-branch-r)

Comment: By the way, `-l` probably does not do what you want. Generally, [it creates reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--l), but here it is probably just omitted. For listing all branches, `git branch -a` is enough.

Comment: @ColinDBennett No.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No, no need to clean up: it is the symbolic branch referenced by your remote repo.
When you clone your repo, you will be by default on the branch referenced by `remotes/origin/HEAD`.

See also:

- "[Git: Correct way to change Active Branch in a bare repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301956/git-correct-way-to-change-active-branch-in-a-bare-repository/3302018#3302018)"
- "[How do I change a Git remote HEAD to point to something besides “master”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485578/how-do-i-change-a-git-remote-head-to-point-to-something-besides-master/2962737)"
- "[How does `origin/HEAD` get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set)"

Note: on Git versions older than 2.20, you need to [use `git branch --list` (or `git branch`), not `git branch -l`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431590/6309).

Comment: Thx for the concise answer and the links. I guess I was confused because I compared this test repo to another one that didn't have the remotes/origin/HEAD reference.
That other repo was the original repo that I pushed to github, hence had never been cloned. Is it correct that this (not having been cloned) is the reason that it doesn't contain the HEAD reference?

Comment: If you do want to remove it: `git remote set-head origin -d`, per http://stackoverflow.com/a/6838756.

Comment: What's the difference between second branch and third branch?

Comment: @Goldname The second branch is not a branch, but a symbolic pointer (HEAD) to a branch. It references the default branch that will be checked out when you are cloning the remote repo.

Comment: @VonC Ok so the second line tells you of the pointer to a branch and what the branch is, right? And the third line lists the branch

Comment: @Goldname Yes, pointer (in the '`remotes`' namespace) and then branch (in the '`remotes`' namespace): they are copies of what was last fetched from the remote repo named `origin`.

Comment: @VonC Thanks, but I'm getting more confused. "copies of what was last fetched" How is a list of branches related to fetching?

Comment: @Goldname Because a branch is a pointer to the most recent commit, itself referencing to the history of past commits. Whenever you fetch, you are getting all new commits, and updating remotes/origin/master to the most recent of those new commits. To know more about branches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51224861/6309, about fetching: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341622/6309, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530333/6309

Answer (score 41):

You can use `git remote set-head origin -d` to delete the `origin/HEAD` symbolic ref, or `git remote set-head origin -a` to query the remote and automatically set the `origin/HEAD` pointer to the remote's current branch.

The `origin/HEAD` reference is optional.  It only acts as a syntactic shortcut:  If it exists and points to `origin/master`, you can use specific simply `origin` where you would otherwise specify `origin/master`.

The [git remote(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) man page describes this:

> set-head
>
> Sets or deletes the default branch (i.e. the target of the
>   symbolic-ref refs/remotes//HEAD) for the named remote. Having a
>   default branch for a remote is not required, but allows the name of
>   the remote to be specified in lieu of a specific branch. For example,
>   if the default branch for origin is set to master, then origin may be
>   specified wherever you would normally specify origin/master.

Comment: is it possible to call `git branch -l -a` or similar, and filter out the HEAD and other symbolic refs?

Comment: You could use `git branch --list -a | grep -v ' -> '`

Comment: sure, but this hack is very unreliable. how to know all "exceptions"...