# how to push to the right branch in git

Tags: git

I'm working with git and I've created a local branch called `feature/rawfeature_scoring`. I'd like to push my local changes to the same remote branch but when I do "git branch -a" I get the following information and I'm not sure what this line means

```
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop
```

does that mean if I do `git push`, it pushed to develop branch?

I believe my local and remote branches are a bit messed up and my current local branch is not following the right remote branch. How can I fix this?

[image]

When I do `git branch -vv`, this is what I get.

[image]

Comment: Do a `git branch -vv` to make sure, your branch will be in the list and you'll see the upstream destination on the same line.

Comment: I did that and updated my original post with the result, does that look ok? when I do git push it pushed my changes to the right remote branch?

Comment: Yes, the tracking is fine (`origin/feature/rawfeature_scoring`). However, the remote has a commit you don't have yet, you'll have to pull before you push.

Comment: In the future please copy and paste test instead of using an image.

Comment: what does   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop mean?

Comment: Committing and pushing are two different things, are you aware? I ask because I would change the title to match the question (e.g., "how to push the right branch") but I want to be certain I'm not changing the intent of the question. :)

Comment: For what `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/develop` means [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12613793/1858327).