# Can't remove a remote git branch

Tags: git

This is what I'm doing.... how do I get rid of the origin remote branch?  And what is it?

```
[master] /dir: git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

[master] /dir: git remote show
github

[master] /dir: git branch -r
  github/master
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master

[master] /dir: git branch -rd origin/HEAD
error: remote branch 'origin/HEAD' not found.

[master] /dir: git branch -rd origin
error: remote branch 'origin' not found.

[master] /dir: git branch -rd origin/HEAD -> origin/master
-bash: origin/master: No such file or directory

[master] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/asanawww: git branch -rd origin/master
error: remote branch 'origin/master' not found.

[master] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/asanawww: git push origin :master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried

```
git gc --prune=now
```

with no luck

Comment: `origin/HEAD` is not a branch, it is a reference pointing to `origin/master`, which is the branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry that I don't haven enough reputation to add a comment.

I realize it is really a comment rather than an answer, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354312/why-is-origin-head-shown-when-running-git-branch-r) question may help.

The solution:

```
git remote set-head origin -d
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do:

```
git branch -rd origin/master
```

Take into consideration that this command will delete the remote branch locally, that is the 'origin/master' reference that is kept in your repository. If that branch still exists in the remote the 'origin/master' reference will be created again when there is a pull or a fetch.

To properly delete it from the remote you can use:

```
git push origin :master
```

This `<local>:<remote>` notation means that the `<local>` reference will be pushed as the `<remote>` branch. By using `:master` you mean that "no reference" is to pushed as master, thus deleting it.

Yet another alternative is to do a delete push:

```
git push --delete origin master
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I tried the commands above and they failed - I believe it's because the remote origin doesn't exist?
error: remote branch 'origin/master' not found.
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove the work-tree associated with local branch (in case it was checked into another directory)

```
git worktree remove work-tree-directory --force //use force if its dirty
```

then you can delete the branch using

```
 git branch -D branch-to-delete  // -D is for force delete, for normal use -d
```