# Git: dealing with remote branches from a removed remote

Tags: git, git-remote

1. `git branch -a` shows `remotes/team/master` and `remotes/team/my-branch`
2. `git remote rm team` says `"error: Could not remove config section 'remote.team'"` (because I edited the config file with a text editor).

Since the `team` remote is gone, how can I delete these (local) remote branches?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24984486/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete remote tracking branches:

```
git branch -rd team/master
```

`-r` means remote. So `-rd` means to delete remote tracking branches.

To automatically remote any remote tracking branches which don't have an upstream branch anymore:

```
git remote prune
```

Comment: `git remote prune team` fails because `team` is not found. `git branch -rd team/master` works great.  Thanks!

Comment: `git branch -rd team/HEAD` does not work.  Any idea how to get rid of that one?

Comment: Found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6838756/23566): `git remote set-head team -d`