# Remove remote tracking branches for removed remote

Tags: git

If I remove a remote from my repo (suppose I delete the remote `origin`), is there a quick way to remove all of the remote tracking branches for that remote?

I'm aware of `git branch -dr`, but I'd have to do this one time for each tracking branch AFAIK. There is also `git remote prune` but I think that requires the name of the remote, which no longer exists in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove a [remote](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), all remote tracking branches are removed automatically:

> remove
>   rm
>   Remove the remote named `<name>`. All remote-tracking branches and configuration settings for  the remote are removed.

Comment: This depends on how the remote was removed - if you do `git remote rm`, then things should get cleaned up. However, if you edit your `.git/config` manually, the rest of the process will need to be done manually, too...

Comment: Good point. In this case, I think, "rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/<REMOTE_NAME>" should work.

Comment: I'm thinking a `git branch ...` approach is better, since you've also got `.git/logs/refs/...`, and `.git/refs/remotes/...` may actually be in `.git/packed-refs`, and so on... Painful as it is, a loop around `git branch -d` is probably the right approach...

Comment: I think that removing remote with "git remote rm" is even better.

Comment: I agree, but the context of the OP's question seems to indicate that it's too late for that...

Answer (score 1):

Note: while `git remote rm` should clean up branches, know that, starting with git 2.0.1 (June 25th, 2014), a `git remote rm` **starts by removing the remote tracking branches**.

See [commit b07bdd3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b07bdd3472886cbdd412ee3e7489273522c43133) by [Jens Lindström (`jensl`)](https://github.com/jensl)

#### `remote rm`: delete remote configuration as the last

> When removing a remote, delete the remote-tracking branches before deleting the remote configuration.
>   **This way, if the operation fails or is aborted while deleting the remote-tracking branches, the command can be rerun to complete the operation**.

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9e768bb77762765f739fffb5c09d0888f3de20e

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on a repository (I removed the remote some time ago but for some reason unclear to me the remote branches remained).  I figured out you can just add a new remote with the old name and then directly remove it:

```
git remote add foo <some url>
git remote rm foo
```

After that the `foo/...` remote branches were gone.