# How to make Head point to master in git?

Tags: git

Please help to make Head point to master in git

[image: git problem image]

I tried to

```
git rebase HEAD master
```

and

```
git checkout master
```

Nothing of those helps.

Updated:
Strange I tried:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
```

then

```
git rev-parse refs/heads/master
fc550e5ff2fe49d64ee1d8bf0da09b2b24bf2cd7
```

and then I got strange warning after the following command

```
git rev-parse HEAD
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
fc550e5ff2fe49d64ee1d8bf0da09b2b24bf2cd7
```

New Update:
There was HEAD branch in remotes -> origin . After removing it everything is ok. I do not have that warning anymore.

Comment: Great. I have included your conclusion in my answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 10):

IF you don't have any local work in progress:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard     # reset HEAD to the master branch
```

But, if '`HEAD`' is *also* the name of a *branch*:

1. Don't do that. `HEAD` shouldn't be the name of a branch: [rename it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch).
2. You can try a:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge HEAD
   ```

Which should fast-forward that branch to `master`.

---

Actually, the OP confirms:

> There was `HEAD` branch in remotes/origin.
>   After removing it everything is ok. I do not have that warning anymore.

Note this is different [from `origin/HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354312/6309), which identifies the default branch on that remote repository.

Comment: What does `git reset --hard` do?