# Git: push was executed with `--set-upstream origin master` to not empty repo

Tags: git

I a very very beginner with git. I've read that `git push --set-upstream origin master` must be executed only once - when repo is empty.

However, I forgot and pushed with `--set-upstream origin master` second time. Now, when I do `git branch -a` I  get

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

What does it mean and what I should do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I a very very beginner with git. I've read that `git push --set-upstream origin master` must be executed only once - when repo is empty.

That's not quite right, in two different ways.  One of them is that this is OK:

> However, I forgot and pushed with `--set-upstream origin master` second time.

You can do this as many times as you like.

The second flaw in the original claim is that you never *have* to do it even once.  It's both convenient and a *good idea* to do it once, on the first `git push`, but it's not a *requirement*.<sup>1</sup>  Moreover, it's a good idea to do it once *for each new-to-them branch*,<sup>2</sup> not just if the upstream repository is empty.  That is, "first push" does not mean "first push ever" but rather "first push per new branch".

Every time you use the `-u` or `--set-upstream` option with `git push`, you set, or re-set (i.e., do not change), or even *do* change, the *upstream* setting for the branch you just pushed.  Pushing branch *B* to the remote named `origin` creates or updates your `origin/B` *remote-tracking branch*,<sup>3</sup> and then sets *B*'s upstream to `origin/B`.  If it was already set like that, no problem!  If it was not set at all, now it's set: yay!  If it was set *differently*, now it's set to `origin/B.`  If that's how you want it set: yay!  This is only bad if that's *not* how you want it set (which seems pretty unlikely).

To understand *why* you would want to set or change the upstream, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770744/1256452) to a related question.  Note that you can also *unset* the upstream of any given branch.

To see more history, of how this used to work in the bad old days with Git version 1.7 and earlier, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18031946/1256452) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/1256452).

[Dhiraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43032994/1256452) explains what you are seeing now.

---

<sup>1</sup>Using `-u` is not a requirement per se.  But, if the other Git repository, the one to which you are pushing, does not *have* a branch of the same name, *and* your `push.default` configuration is `simple`, your alternative to `git push -u origin master` is `git push origin master:master`, i.e., you would have to specify the branch name twice.  Writing `-u` once is shorter, *and* sets your `master`'s upstream to the newly-created `origin/master`, which is a good thing—so it's shorter and better to use `-u` once, but it is not *required*.

<sup>2</sup>When you run `git push` or `git fetch`—or `git pull`, which just runs `git fetch` and then a second Git command—you have your Git call up another Git.  That other Git has *its own* branches.  Those branches have their own commits, which may or may not match your commits on your branches.  Obviously, a new, completely-empty repository has *no* commits (and therefore no branches),<sup>4</sup> but if you have created a new branch named `zorg`, *their* Git probably does not yet have a `zorg`: the branch will be new to them.

<sup>3</sup>Your remote-tracking branches—such as `origin/master`—are a way for *your* Git to remember, for your convenience, what *your* Git got from *their* (origin's) Git regarding *their* branches, the last time you ran `git fetch` or `git push` to `origin`.  This is what they are for.  Use `git fetch` (or `git remote update`) to update them all, from time to time, whenever you think they might have changed and you want to find out.

<sup>4</sup>Philosophical question: what does it mean for a branch to exist, yet have no commits?  *Is* there such thing as an "empty branch"?  (The answer for Git is mostly *no, there is no such thing*, but there are other version control systems—and I just said "mostly"....)

Comment: Very nice explaination torek.

Answer (score 1):

At GitHub, you can select which branch is checked out by default (i.e. when you clone). By default, origin/HEAD will point at that.

Please refer this link for more details
 [Why is "origin/HEAD" shown when running "git branch -r"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354312/why-is-origin-head-shown-when-running-git-branch-r)